# Calling a public class inside a public class, from a different package

Tags: java, class, package

Here is my problem:

I setup 4 classes (All public) like this:

```
Package main
--Class Tuna
Package second
--Class Apple
----Class InsideApple
--Class Orange
```

Code for each one:

```
public class Tuna {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Orange orange = new Orange();
        orange.callApple();

        Apple apple = new Apple();

        System.out.println("A call from orange");
        apple.callApple();
        apple.insideApple.callInsideApple(); // This line will crash it -- Why?
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Apple{

        public void callApple(){
            System.out.println("Here is Apple!");
        }

        InsideApple insideApple = new InsideApple();

        public class InsideApple{

            public void callInsideApple(){
                System.out.println("Here is Inside Apple!");
            }

        }

    }
```

---

```
public class Orange{

    Apple apple = new Apple();

    public void callApple(){
        System.out.println("A call from orange");
        apple.callApple();
        apple.insideApple.callInsideApple();
    }

}
```

As you see the 4th class (InsideApple) is a public class inside class (Apple)
When i try to call a method inside class (InsideApple) from class (Orange) i got no problem.
But when i try to do it from class (Tuna) its says that there is no instacne for class (InsideApple) inside class (Apple)

What can i do to prevent this? I know if i put all the classes in a single package it will be fixed. But thats a dumb way to fix it i think. Do you guys have any better iders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do change the visibility of insideApple from default to public

```
public InsideApple insideApple = new InsideApple();
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot declare multiple public class within one file and you can't declare a class within another class, your Apple.java file should be similar to the following:

```
public class Apple{

    public InsideApple insideApple = new InsideApple();

    public void callApple(){
        System.out.println("Here is Apple!");
    }

} 
class InsideApple{

    public void callInsideApple(){
        System.out.println("Here is Inside Apple!");
    }

}
```

Also, as you can see, the insideApple variable should be public so that it can be accessed from other classes.